# How can I view the list of hot network questions using the Stack Exchange Android app?

Tags: support, android-app, hot-questions

I have the Stack Exchange Android app and use it often just to look at new and interesting questions. There's a widget which shows random questions from the list of "hot network questions." However within the app itself, there appears to be no way to browse the list.

Is there a way to view the list of hot network questions from the Stack Exchange Android app?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As of current version (v1.0.73, but probably [since v1.0.69](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/260498/app-keeps-crashing-rendering-error-since-update-to-1-0-68#comment851160_260498)), there's Hot Network Question on the top of the feed, and there is "View more hot questions" button below it. Tapping it will list the Hot Network Questions.